# How to import Redshift table to H2O Flow?

Tags: python, amazon-redshift, h2o

I am trying to import redshift table to H20 flow and using the following URL as in other db editors ie.

jdbc:redshift://xxxx.xxxxzubx6zm.us-west-2.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/dev in the URL string where it does mention use the jdbc format of url

But it is failing with :

java.lang.RuntimeException: SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc://

How to add a suitable driver if required and is it possible to connect Redshift cluster to H2O?

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection.html#download-jdbc-driver

Comment: it doesn't look like you downloaded the JDBC driver. did you supply a JDBC driver to the Java runtime H2O is running on (the driver has to be present on classpath)?

Comment: @Lauren, How to select this driver I could not find much help in docs

Answer (score 0):

For details on how to set up your JDBC driver or [allowed data sources](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/getting-data-into-h2o.html?#data-sources) see the documentation [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/getting-data-into-h2o.html?#jdbc-databases). Feel free to update your question, if you run into issues getting setup.

Here is the [list](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/getting-data-into-h2o.html?#supported-file-formats) of acceptable file formats:

```
H2O currently supports the following file types:

CSV (delimited) files (including GZipped CSV)
ORC
SVMLight
ARFF
XLS (BIFF 8 only)
XLSX (BIFF 8 only)
Avro version 1.8.0 (without multifile parsing or column type modification)
Parquet
```

Comment: in the documentation, jdbc:redshift://xxxx.xxxxzubx6zm.us-west-2.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/dev is a working jdbc url, infact i use same for my ide. but it fails to connect with this in h20 flow. its not about file formats but database connectivity with fetch data from tables